# how to correctly transmit an event from a child component of vue3?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

Is it possible to pass an event from a child component without passing it to the parent component itself, so as not to duplicate it and without Vuex

```html
     HEADER
      <p>{{ count }}</p>
      <allItems @addToCart="countCart" />
      <script>
       import { ref } from 'vue'
        const count = ref(0)
       import allItems from '@/views/allItems.vue';
         data: () => ({count}),
         methods: {
        countCart() {
         this.count += 1
        }
         }
      </script>
      /HEADER
      COMPONENT
       <div class="btn me-md-2" id="btn"    @click="addTo(value)">
         <script>
         methods: {
       addTo(value){
       this.$emit('addToCart', value)
         }
         }
      </script>
      /COMPONENT
```